# Is it possible to script a moving part that touches a model and the model will disappear once broken?

Tags: lua, roblox

I scripted a button so I can spawn the model in but I want to know if I can make a script that when the model is touched by a part it will disappear?

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

Use Roblox's collision detection to trigger that.

Implement a listener for the Touched event and then you'd probably make it invisible setting the Transparency property of the BasePart to 1. Make it explode or whatever you like.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/BasePart/Transparency

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/detecting-collisions

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Explosion

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to detect when a model is touched using a .Touched event. The best course of action for this is to set a primary part to the model (using a script or in the model's properties). Then in the script, you first detect if the part is touched: `model.PrimaryPart.Touched:Connect(function())` then you loop though all the **parts** in the model (BaseParts) and destroy them:
`for i, v in pairs(model:GetChildren()) do`
`if v:IsA("BasePart") then`
`v:Destroy()` <- or however you want the parts in the model to disappear
`end`
`end`